# Couldn't find Todo with 'id'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Hello everyone I have searched high and low for an answer to this problem, so I am finally going to ask it here. I'm a very new programmer trying to learn html and ruby. I am coding a very simple todo app but I cannot figure out how to fix this error:

"Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=#"

> todos_controlller.rb

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

def index
  @todos = Todo.all 

end

def new
  @todo = Todo.new
end


def edit
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)
    redirect_to todos_path
end

private 
def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:item)end


end
```

here are my views

> new.html.slim

```
= form_for (@todo) do |f|
 p
   = f.text_field :item, :placeholder => "Add new item"
 p
   = f.submit
```

> edit.html.slim

```
= form_for(@link) do |f|
 p
   = f.text_field :item
 p
   = f.submit
```

> index.html.slim

```
- @todos.each do |todo|
  ul
        li=todo.item 

p
 = link_to "New", new_todo_path
p
 = link_to "Edit", edit_todo_path(@todos)
p
 = link_to "Delete", '#'
```

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: "todos#index"
 resources :todos
end
```

EDIT:

> My edit view exactly as it is written now

```
= form_for(@todo) do |f|
  p
   = f.text_field :item
  p
   = f.submit
```

I am going off this tutorial http://masteruby.github.io/weekly-rails/2014/03/22/how-to-create-todo-list-app-static-pages.html#.VA8t4_ldU3l

Apologies if my format is wrong, first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your index.html.slim you need to pass a single value of todo not all the todos:

```
// @todos contains a collection of all the todos
- @todos.each do |todo|
  // inside this block todo contains your single todo
  ul
    li=todo.item 
  p
    = link_to "New", new_todo_path
  p
    = link_to "Edit", edit_todo_path(todo) #notice it's todo not @todos
  p
    = link_to "Delete", '#'
```

***This will resolve your above error but you have another error in your your edit.html.slim so you need to fix that as well otherwise it'll give you another error, in your form you have to use @todo not @link***

```
= form_for @todo do |f|
  // fields
```

Also if you want to show validation errors for your form then in your create method you should use .save instead of .create, checkout [`Displaying Validation errors in views`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views)

Comment: I think something is wrong with my gems or rails or something? I exactly copied your codee and it gave me another error "C:/row/todo-list-app/app/views/todos/index.html.slim:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' " -_-

Comment: Yes I will delete earlier ones, sorry.

Comment: @dwagz1313 can you show full error and on which line you are getting this

Comment: C:/row/todo-list-app/app/views/todos/index.html.slim:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' ; @output_buffer.safe_concat(("</p>")); end; @output_buffer ^ C:/row/todo-list-app/app/views/todos/index.html.slim:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'



   "Extracted source (around line #22):      
  p
    = link_to "Delete", '#'"

Comment: @dwagz1313 again this looks more of an indentation error, as i just explained you in my previous comment when you use haml or slim you don't close block. Just try to make sure everything is properly indented

Comment: I FINALLY DID IT, I don't even know what I did. Some random space. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to link the edit link to all @todos, but it should be linked to a single `todo`:

```
= link_to "Edit", edit_todo_path(todo)
```